# why is latex's ltluatex.sty required for plain luaotfload?

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, luaotfload

I tried (successfully) to compile a sober Plain LuaTeX format and discovered, with some surprise, that loading the standard `luaotfload`er in Plain requires a piece of code, `ltluatex.tex` which requires installing `LaTeX-base`. I'm not interested in LaTeX; why this requirement? I mean: to me, this seems like a typical `generic` macro, not necessarily tied to LaTeX.

Comment: well "the standard loader" is a sty, and so a typical latex file which also work in plain.  luaotfload, ltluatex.tex and ltluatex.lua are maintained by the latex team.

Comment: so: the support target has always been latex, from context; plain compatibility is somehow a side effect. correct?

Comment: only the original authors can say something about the "always" and the original target. But plain compatibiblity is not only a side effect, LaTeX normally tries to support plain too where sensible, see e.g. miniltx and the graphics support.

Comment: If you are searching a minimal macro file which provides OTF fonts for LuaTeX, you can use `\input luafonts.tex`. But the lua code is imported from `loaotfload` package anyway.

Comment: @wipet I just wanted to know why Plain's attempt to load `luaotfload.sty` required a LaTeX base file (and its payload). And by my truth, I don't know where is this `luafonts.tex` file anyway.

Comment: @jarnosz The `luafonts.tex` file is a part of csplain package and this package is part of TeXlive or MikTeX. So, you can find this file in TeXlive or MikTeX.

Comment: So: `luafonts.tex` is part of `csplain`, as much as `ltluatex.sty` is part of `latex-base`; and both require the full `luaotfload` bundle... I would not call either "minimal" in any respect. :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two parts to an answer here. The first is that `luaotfload` needs a certain amount of data structures to be available from the 'TeX side'. That means that some basic resource handling is needed in macro code.

The second part is that over time the LaTeX team have picked up various parts of this setup as it is essential for using LaTeX with LuaTeX. Earlier, there were at least two important package (`luatex` and `luatexbase`), with a resulting complexity in support/compatibility. The LaTeX team wanted to avoid a situation where using LaTeX at all (for LuaTeX users) needed external ('contrib') code, so took steps to address this. The result was `ltluatex`, which was written from the start anticipating loading by both plain and LaTeX users.

As this support is required by the LaTeX kernel, it's distributed as part of the core LaTeX bundle so lives inside (for CTAN) `latex-base`. However, like `color.sty` or `graphics.sty`, it's always going to be supported for use with the plain format. (More specifically, the code is not loaded by LaTeX as a separate file, but is directly incorporated into `latex.ltx`. As such, the source file `ltluatex.dtx` cannot be distributed separately from the LaTeX core, as this would make the LaTeX situation more complex.)

Comment: So: iiuc, `ltluatex` is so crucial for LuaTeX support in LaTeX, that it cannot be developed/distributed separately. By contrast, the `graphics` bundle is not part of the LaTeX "kernel", and thus has its own Plain interface separately in `miniltx`, In other words: since you may use LaTeX without `graphics` support with any engine, the bundle is not part of the kernel, even if marked as "required"; on the other hand, since you cannot use LaTeX with LuaTeX without some interface to the otf fonts, the interface to the `luaotfload` font handler is embedded in the kernel. Correct?

Comment: @jarnosz Broadly yes. The aim with LuaTeX has been to make sure things work 'out of the box', which means that the kernel needs `luaotfload` support. Starting today one would do the same for graphics, but as this was historically separate, it's not about to change.