# How can I use these PostScript fonts on Overleaf with plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, overleaf, plain-tex

How can I use these fonts on Overleaf with plain TeX?

```
\font\tenpalatino=Palatino at 10pt
\font\bighelvetica=Helvetica at 30pt

This is a test. \tenpalatino This is Palatino font at 10pt. \par
\bighelvetica This is Helvetica font at 30pt. 

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Use standard names like, Roman `pplr8t`, italic `pplri8t`, bold `pplb8t` and bold-italic `pplbi8t` and smallcaps `pplbc8t` for font names, e.g., `\font\tenpalatino=pplr8t at 10pt`

Comment: Which engine are you trying to run? You must give PDFTeX a `tfm` (TeX font metrics) file to set it up; and as the other comment implies, most PostScript font metrics files have peculiar filenames documented in Karl Berry's [paper](https://www.tug.org/fontname/fontname.pdf)

Comment: @jarnosz I'm using Overleaf with `LaTeX` engine to run plain TeX. Just a beginer and want to learn LaTeX begining from TeX.

Comment: The code above is from a book I'm reading but it doesn't compile so I made this question.

Comment: what's that book's title, if you don't mind?

Comment: then, I assume you are following [these instructions from Overleaf's page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Can_I_run_plain_TeX_on_Overleaf%3F), correct?

Comment: @jarnosz yes, I followed that. 
The book is A Beginner’s Book of TeX  by Raymond Seroul and Silvio Levy.

Comment: I see; that book may not assume the Berry fontname convention, which became a sort of standard before Unicode, iirc.

Comment: My solution will work with every engine, as they all share the TeX font metrics common denominator, even if you remove the `%&pdftex` directive.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want some of the Standard Postscript fonts, beware that you must give the [PDF]TeX engine a `tfm` (TeX font metrics) file to set it up; and as stated in the comments to your question, most PostScript font metrics files have peculiar filenames documented in Karl Berry's paper on [TUGBoat 11-1990](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-4/tb30berry.pdf) and the reference guide on the [tug website](https://www.tug.org/fontname/fontname.pdf). Given that info, the following should work in any engine, provided you have followed [the instructions given in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Can_I_run_plain_TeX_on_Overleaf%3F) to set up a custom TeX engine in your `latexmkrc` file.

```
\font\tenpalatino=pplr8y at 10pt
\font\bighelvetica=phvr8y at 30pt

This is a test. \tenpalatino This is Palatino font at 10pt. \par
\bighelvetica This is Helvetica font at 30pt. 

\bye
```

That convention is already present in Example 7, Section 3 of [TeX for the Impatient](https://ctan.org/pkg/impatient).

[image: sample postscript fonts on pdftex]

Answer (score 2):

If you're not a plain TeX purist that even refuses to look in LaTeX files, you can see that `palatino.sty` has

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

The default output encoding of LaTeX reflects the plain TeX setup for fonts, so you want to look at `ot1ppl.fd`

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{m}{n}{<-> pplr7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{m}{sc}{<-> pplrc7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{m}{sl}{<-> pplro7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{m}{it}{<-> pplri7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{b}{n}{<-> pplb7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{b}{sc}{<-> pplbc7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{b}{sl}{<-> pplbo7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ppl}{b}{it}{<-> pplbi7t}{}
```

(slightly edited for compactness). You therefore want

```
\font\tenpalatino=pplr7t at 10pt
```

because this correspond to medium weight (`m`) and normal (`n`) shape.  The standard design size for PostScript fonts is 10pt, so you may even omit `at 10pt`.

Similarly, looking in `ot1phv` shows that the declaration you need is

```
\font\bighelvetica=phvr7t at 30pt
```

Full example, also showing accents.

```
\font\tenpalatino=pplr7t at 10pt
\font\bighelvetica=phvr7t at 30pt

This is a t\^est. \tenpalatino This is Palatino f\'ont at 10pt. \par
\bighelvetica This is Helvetica f\"o\~nt at 30pt. 

\bye
```

[image]

Beware that these fonts don't contain Greek letters, so you need to define them separately if you want to use them in math.

Comment: @jarnosz A class of people that I think doesn’t exist.

Comment: @jarnosz So, where's the rudeness? My dictionary says “a person who adheres strictly to the basic principles of any subject or discipline”.

Comment: @jarnosz I don't think that applies, but I changed the wording nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

Use `luahbtex` and file names:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\tenpalatino="file:texgyrepagella-regular.otf" at 10pt
\font\bighelvetica="file:texgyreheros-regular.otf" at 30pt

This is a test. \tenpalatino This is Palatino font at 10pt. \par
\bighelvetica This is Helvetica font at 30pt. 

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: This suggestion may work, if you are a "LaTeX fundamentalist", who does not mind throwing L3 code into a Plain solution.

Comment: `luaotfload` simplifies the loading of OpenType fonts. That's all. It has nothing to do with LaTeX

Comment: actually, it does: `luaofload.sty` has a call to `ltluatex.tex`, which is part of the LaTeX kernel, to do the rest of the stuff, if you check the [luaotfload](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/blob/main/src/luaotfload.sty) and [latex](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/main/texmf/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.tex) repositories, and [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625735/why-is-latexs-ltluatex-sty-required-for-plain-luaotfload).

Comment: "Part of the LaTeX kernel" doesn't mean that it is pure LaTeX code...

Comment: I am ready to concede that, if you acknowledge that it has *something* to do with LaTeX.

Comment: @jarnosz OK, luaotfload has something to do with LaTeX. But its great part of the code is borrowed from fontloader from ConTeXt. So, we can say that this has something to do with ConTeXt too. And, sure, it has nothing to do with L3 code.

Comment: @wipet: both gladly conceded. still, the OP was asking about the resources available at the time of Seroul and Levy, neither luaotfload nor ConTeXt were available at the time, and the "old" solution still works even on LuaHBTeX.